# Is it possible to use file array in lambda expression and let it update?

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

The block I am using is running a foreach loop on string arraylist, in lambda. The expression is trying to filter out the list of files which matches the pattern and stores it in file array.

Issue here is array list will run for n number of times and it will update the file array that many times.
I need a correct solution which will allow the use lambda, will allow to look for all the pattern in one path and allows that to store in one file array.

Wrong code which I am using is,

```
File[] fileList2 = null;
ArrayList<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<>();
String line = bufReader.readLine();
while (line != null) 
{
  listOfLines.add(line); 
  line = bufReader.readLine(); 
}
bufReader.close();
listOfLines.forEach((n) -> 
{
    fileList2 = new File("directory/path/").listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {
        public boolean accept(File arg0, String arg1)
        {
            boolean result;
            if(arg1.contains(n))
                result=true;
            else
                result=false;
            return result;
        }
    });
});
```

My approach is not correct cause, for each iteration fileList2 will be updated, which is not required.

I am also getting an error for same reason

> Local variable fileList2 defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the error, because the fileList2 set to something different every time the lambda is called rewriting the foreach part to a normal loop better reveals what's happening

```
File[] fileList2 = null;
...
for (String line : listOfLines) {
    fileList2 = new File("directory/path/").listFiles(...
    ...
}
```

as you can see the fileList2 is then only set to an array of files that has something to do with the last entry in the listOfLines.

BTW you can change

```
boolean result;
if(arg1.contains(n))
    result=true;
else
    result=false;
return result;
```

to a single line of code ...

```
return arg1.contains(n);
```